# How to get Microsoft Live profile URL using the ProviderKey value

Tags: oauth, owin, asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-live-connect

I'm trying to figure out if there's a URL I can use to point to a Microsoft Live user profile,

For example, facebook allows https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{ProviderKey value}

What would it be for Microsoft?

https://account.microsoft.com/profile/{ProviderKey value} ??

Answer (score 0):

These two seem to work today, but there is no guarantee they will continue to do so:

- http://cid-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.profile.live.com/
- https://profile.live.com/cid-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the user's 16-char alphanumeric ID.